# Inverting scaling in scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(data_train)
data_train = scaler.transform(data_train)
data_test = scaler.transform(data_test)
```

Hello,
I've created a neural network and I'm trying to rescale the output back to original value. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for that. So if the data you want to change back is x

```
scaler.inverse_transform(x)
```

For more information you can have a look at the documentation:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html